# Can I color the empty space between two objects?

Tags: materials

[image]

How do I color in the space between the torus and the cylinder? I want to do this without changing the color outside the torus.

Comment: if there is a face inside the torus assign different material to that area, or create circle and scale it to fit inside the torus and give it a color, or use a texture

Comment: @Chebhou You should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

you have many options :

- create another material with a different color
- select the face you want to color and click on **assign** in the **Material** tab

[image]

OR

- create another object that fits inside the torus and give it another material

[image]

OR

- use a texture  and unwrap the object to map it correctly

[image]

Comment: Second choice can be shorter, just select an inner loop, duplicate and separate it as a separate object and fill it.

Comment: yes that will fit in perfectly

Comment: I don't get it, also my circles are transparent when I place them in.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev yes they are, you should go to edit mode and hit 'F' this will create a face inside the circle; all the verticies should be selected

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev you're welcome , side note: to make this circle follows one of the other objects select it then select the other object and hit  'Ctrl'+'P'